# Not able to create UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on View WITH SCHEMABINDING having sub queries

Tags: sql-server-2012

**Below is the code:**

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_GetAllContents] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT C.ContentID,
       C.Title,
       C.[Description],
       C.Tags,
       C.Markets,
       C.Formats,
       C.Categories,
       C.IsGlobalSalesResource,
       C.IsActive,
       C.CreatedBy,
       C.CreatedDate,
       C.ModifiedBy,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT ',' + T.TagName
                FROM [dbo].[Tags] T
                WHERE T.IsActive=1
                  AND T.TagID IN
                    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(items))
                     FROM [dbo].[SplitString](C.Tags, ','))
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS TagNames,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT ',' + M.MarketName
                FROM [dbo].[Markets] M
                WHERE M.IsActive=1
                  AND M.MarketID IN
                    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(items))
                     FROM [dbo].[SplitString](C.Markets, ','))
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS MarketNames,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT ',' + F.FormatName
                FROM [dbo].[Formats] F
                WHERE F.IsActive=1
                  AND F.FormatID IN
                    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(items))
                     FROM [dbo].[SplitString](C.Formats, ','))
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS FormatNames,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT ',' + Ca.CategoryName
                FROM [dbo].[Categories] Ca
                WHERE Ca.IsActive=1
                  AND Ca.CategoryID IN
                    (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(items))
                     FROM [dbo].[SplitString](C.Categories, ','))
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS CategorieNames,
       STUFF(
               (SELECT '$A$' + cast(A.AttachmentID AS varchar) + '$,$' + cast(A.ActualFileName AS nvarchar(1000))
                FROM [dbo].[Attachments] A
                WHERE A.ContentID=C.ContentID
                  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 3, '') AS Attachments
FROM [dbo].[Contents] C GO
```

**Error on below code:**

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_View_GetAllContents_ContentID] ON [dbo].[View_GetAllContents](ContentID);

GO
```

**Exception:**
Cannot create index on view "SM_SalesWarehouse.dbo.View_GetAllContents" because it contains one or more subqueries. Consider changing the view to use only joins instead of subqueries. Alternatively, consider not indexing this view.

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the error message? Are you having trouble implementing its advice? If so, what are you stuck on? The simplest workaround is to remove the index -- SQL Server can't maintain an index like this automatically or efficiently (and "why" should be obvious when you start thinking about what that would involve when any table contents change).

Comment: I was trying to Implement SQL Server Full-Text Search on creating full text catalog.

Comment: You'll have to materialize the view manually, by creating a new, separate table for it, and scheduling a job that dumps the view to this table. Refreshing the contents piecemeal based on triggers is also an option, but this can get very complicated or inefficient, depending on how often the related tables change. Alternatively, import data in an alternative system dedicated to FTS, like Elasticsearch, or a NoSQL solution like MongoDB if you actually need structured documents and not so much FTS.